# css hover div, overlay transparent image on top of inline styled background image

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that has a background image that is added to it with jquery as an inline style.

`<div class="flex_cell" style="background-image: url(img/image.jpg);">`

What I need to do is add another background image, on top of the existing background image, when the div is hovered. The new background image will be a red tinted 50% opaque png.

`div.flex_cell:hover {
background-image: url(img/overlay.png);
}`

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

you could add a pseudo element on hover using `:after` which will contain the overlay png, and if you need to tint the png red using css you can apply a filter and shift its hue:

```css
.flex_cell{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
.flex_cell:hover:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background: url(http://www.granini.com/data/images/fruit_images/full/banana.png) !important;
    opacity:0.7;
 filter: hue-rotate(310deg);
 -moz-filter: hue-rotate(310deg);
 -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(310deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_cell" style="background-image: url(http://foodmatters.tv/images/bananas.jpg);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add only css remove the inline style.. It has hogj sprvificity.

```
Div.flex_cell {
background-image: url(img/image.png);
}
Div.flex_cell:hover {
background-image: url(img/overlay.png);
}
```

Replace this:

```
<div class="flex_cell" style="background-image: url(img/image.jpg);">
```

With

```
<div class="flex_cell" >
```

**Edit**:

If you cant remove inline style add !important

```
Div.flex_cell:hover {
background-image: url(img/overlay.png) !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't remove the inline style. It's added by the Wordpress theme I'm using. When you hover over the div, I need to keep that background image, but add a second, opaque background image on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

In css, an inline styles will be higher up the cascade than attached styles. You simply need to mark your hover override as !important in order for it to take precedence over your inline style.

```
div.flex_cell:hover {
  background-image: url(img/image.jpg) !important;
}
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNRNLy

Alternatively, unless necessary it's better practice to avoid inline.